# How to add T0 values as covariate in a repeated-measures model with lme in R

Tags: longitudinal

I'm analyzing data from a trial done on dairy cows. I want to compare milk production, but I realized that the two groups were not quite equal in milk production at the beginning of the trial.

According to my instructor, I can try to erase the problem by adding t0 values as a covariate in the model (even if it's not sure it will be enough).

However, I don't know how to do it in a repeated-mesures model, using lme. Indeed, I'm face to a major problem : accoring to what I've read online, I have to add the t0 values in a specific column, but when I do this I have an error saying that I have not the same amount of values that in other columns. I tried multiple ways to add it in the model but I always had this issue.

Obviously I don't have the same amount of values in the t0 columns since I'm studying repeated measures : I have to put my data a the format "long", with a columns containing the dates from 1 to n.

Do you know a way to add the t0 values as a covariate in the model please ?

Moreover, I'm using "lme" and not something else because I'm using an automatic script which needed to be done with "lme" for some reasons. So if you manage to find a way with "lme" it would be perfect.

Here is my model :

```
lme(Milk ~ Treatment * factor(Date),
               data = data, 
               random = ~1|Bloc/Treatment,
               correlation = corAR1(form = ~Date|Bloc/Treatment))
```

Thank you in advance for your help !

I tried :

```
lme(Milk ~ Treatment + Milk_t0 * factor(Date),
               data = data, 
               random = ~1|Bloc/Treatment,
               correlation = corAR1(form = ~Date|Bloc/Treatment))
```